# macro started throwing a subscript out of range message

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that was running fine for at least 6 months.  Recently, it started throwing a "subscript out of range" error message when it hits the line below:

```
Do Until Len(Trim(Workbooks(MyReport).Worksheets(Var1(Y)).Cells(r, 1))) + 
    Len(Trim(Workbooks(MyReport).Worksheets(Var1(Y)).Cells(r, 2))) + 
    Len(Trim(Workbooks(MyReport).Worksheets(Var1(Y)).Cells(r, 3))) = 0

    MyReport = "000000-Affliates.xlsx"
    Var1(Y) = "UK-FR Upld"
```

This code has never been an issue before?  Any help would be greatly appreicated.  Thanks........

Comment: That's 3 lines, so which one is the problem?  Also, missing a bunch of context so...

Comment: Looks like the `Trim`s are in the wrong spot.

Comment: ...but that would give you a different error.  Is this your *actual* "used to work" code?

Comment: @TimWilliams.....I've updated the original post to show the original code.  I in advertently posted the revised code I tried.  I also added this line:  gg = Trim(Workbooks(MyReport).Worksheets(Var1(Y)).Trim(Cells(r, 1))) before the "do" and it errors out on this line now.  I'm not sure why this no longer works.  Thanks for the help....

Comment: @BigBen.....I've updated my original post with the original code.  I had posted the "revised" code I was trying to get this to work.  Thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not an issue with the macro.  It was due to the sheet name on the data file.  The user had a couple of spaces in front of the sheet name.  The macro code was trimming all of the spaces in the sheet name so the macro wasn't finding the sheet.

"  sheetname" ≠ "sheetname"

Once I removed the spaces the macro ran as expected.

Thanks for the help.......